# Python: MySQL select null with non null data

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Python Flask and MySQL. I get input from app for name, price and volume to search from MySQL In order to all data.

[image]

The output is as below:

```
name   | Price | Volume
Screw  | 5.0   | 700
iron   | null  | 67
wood   | 23    | null
metal  | 76    | 56
plywood| 100   | null
rebar  | 75    | 59
steel  | null  | 87
L steel| 78    | 65
```

What I required is when I select with a specific range for volume, I would like to excluded null for volume but included null for Price and vice versa.

Scenario 1:

Select volume between 60 to 100, select all form Price and any Name.
[image]

Current output is:

```
name   | Price | Volume
iron   | null  | 67
wood   | 23    | null
plywood| 100   | null
steel  | null  | 87
L steel| 78    | 65
```

Output which I need:

```
name   | Price | Volume
iron   | null  | 67
steel  | null  | 87
L steel| 78    | 65
```

Scenario 2:

Select price between 50 to 120, select all form Volume and any Name.

[image]

Current Output:

```
name   | Price | Volume
iron   | null  | 67
metal  | 76    | 56
plywood| 100   | null
rebar  | 75    | 59
steel  | null  | 87
L steel| 78    | 65
```

Output that I need:

```
name   | Price | Volume
metal  | 76    | 56
plywood| 100   | null
rebar  | 75    | 59
L steel| 78    | 65
```

Below is my code:

```
@app.route('/ABC/search1', methods=['GET'])
def ABCsearch1():
    name = request.args.get('name',default='',type=str)
    priceMin = request.args.get('priceMin',default='',type=str)
    priceMax = request.args.get('priceMax',default='',type=str)
    volMin = request.args.get('volMin',default='',type=str)
    volMax = request.args.get('volMax',default='',type=str)

        limit = request.args.get('limit',default=0,type=int)
    offSet = request.args.get('offSet',default=0,type=int)

    query = """ SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE (Stock LIKE :s0 or Name LIKE :s1 or Number LIKE :s2)
                AND (Price BETWEEN (IF(:s3='_',-5000,:s4)) AND (IF(:s5='_',5000,:s6)) OR Price IS NULL)
                AND (Volume BETWEEN (IF(:s7='_',-5000,:s8)) AND (IF(:s9='_',5000,:s10)) OR Volume IS NULL)
                LIMIT :s95 OFFSET :s96 """
    query = text(query)
    input = {'s0':name+"%",'s1':name+"%",'s2':name+"%",'s3':priceMin,'s4':priceMin,'s5':priceMax,'s6':priceMax,'s7':volMin,'s8':volMin,'s9':volMax,'s10':volMax,

                's95':limit,'s96':offSet}
    try:
        call = db.session.execute(query,input)
        f = call.fetchall()
        col = ['index','Name','Number','Price','id']
        f1 = [OrderedDict(zip(col,t)) for t in f]
    except Exception:
        return 'Error'

    return jsonify({'Stock': f1})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if I understand correctly, it seems you want to send a **different request** based on whether the user specifies a price range or a volume range.

In that case, the simplest solution would be to use if-else statements to check which range has been specified, and modify the query string appropriately.

For example,

```
if (priceMin is None) and (priceMax is None): 
# (Or whatever you want to compare it to)
    query = """blah blah"""
    input = blah blah

else if (volMin is None) and (volMax is None):
    query = """blah blah"""
    input = blah blah

# execute query...
```

Let me know if this helps. By the way, I highly suggest that you use SQLAlchemy instead of creating SQL query string like you have done. It's so much more convenient! You should look at tutorial here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/intro.html#documentation-overview

Comment: It is what I want! However, I thought I am using sqlalchemy, what should you suggest I shall do?

Comment: @bkcollection sorry for the late reply. Sqlalchemy removes the need for you to write out complete query strings in SQL syntax, instead you will simply use a query command such as: 
`items = session.query('Item').filter_by(blah blah blah).first()`

Comment: It's not only more convenient, but also much more stable (safe from errors). Right now you are almost doing the same as using the Python DB-API, which involves writing out complete SQL syntax for every database operation.